# can't run my iphone app on an ipod

Tags: xcode, installation, ipod

I am trying to test my new application i just wrote on my daughters ipod.  I paid the 100 bucks to join development team for apple and then I followed the instructions which were pretty simple.  But now I get the following message when I try to run:

The Info.plist for application at /Users/sarokhatchatourian/Documents/Books_nd_Movies_Seen/build/Debug-iphoneos/Books_nd_Movies_Seen.app specifies a minimum OS version of 4.3, which is too high to be installed on Hailiey’s iPod

Is there some software that I can download or what do I need to do to this ipod?  Is this ipod too old? do I need to update the OS of the ipod?  I am new to this.  Not a mac guy but trying to get there.

Thanks
Saro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Info.plist for application at
>   /Users/sarokhatchatourian/Documents/Books_nd_Movies_Seen/build/Debug-iphoneos/Books_nd_Movies_Seen.app
>   specifies a minimum OS version of 4.3,
>   which is too high to be installed on
>   Hailiey’s iPod

This is your answer. Change the deployment target of the app to an older iOS version or update the ipod to 4.3 or later.